# Bootstrap 5 nav pills active

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to keep the selected nav pills the active after refresh using javascript function in bootstrap 5?
how to keep the selected nav pills the active after refresh using javascript function in bootstrap 5?

how to keep the selected nav pills the active after refresh using javascript function in bootstrap 5?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="">
 <head>
  <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>


<script> 
  
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('button[data-bs-toggle="pill"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('data-bs-target'));
      });
      var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
      if(activeTab){
        $('#pills-tab button[data-bs-target="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
      }
    });

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-12">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-text-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-text" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-text" aria-selected="true">
        Text Emotion
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="pills-audio-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-audio" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-audio" aria-selected="false">
        Get Emotion By Audio
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="pills-comBine-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-comBine" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-comBine" aria-selected="false">
        Get Emotion By Combine audio and text  
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <div class="container mt-12">
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-text" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-text-tab">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2 class="text-primary">Enter the Text to get the Sentiment</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form
              action="/text_emotion_prediction"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
              
              <input
                name="text"
                class="form-control input-lg"
                placeholder="Enter Text Here"
              />
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          
          <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
            {% if class1 %} 
            <h1>Sentiment</h1>
            {{ sentiment }} 
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        
    
      {% if class1 %}
        <h1>Emotion</h1>
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="Image" />
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-audio" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-audio-tab">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2 class="text-primary">Upload audio file to get Sentiment</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form
            action="/audio_emotion_prediction"
            method="post"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
             
            <input type = "file" name = "file" class="form-control" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          
          <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
            {% if audioClass %} 
            <h1>Sentiment</h1>
            {{ audioSentiment }} 
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        
     

    
      {% if audioClass %}
        <h1>Emotion</h1>
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="Image" />
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>



    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-comBine" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-comBine-tab">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i tried to do it with javascript but doesn't work for me please any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [Session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save the last selected nav pills. Then you load it from the storage and use JavaScript to set the selected nav pills.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).